# How to Check If AttributedString isEmpty in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, nsattributedstring, attributedstring

I have `private var remark: AttributedString?`, I want to check is remark is notEmpty then Show the View.

While debugging, I'm getting this

```
(lldb) po remark
▿ Optional<AttributedString>
  ▿ some :      {
    NSStrokeColor = kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0 0 0 1 
    NSStrokeWidth = 0.0
    NSFont = <UICTFont: 0x7ff5bb43d310> font-family: "Times New Roman"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt
    NSColor = kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0 0 0 1 
    SwiftUI.Font = Font(provider: SwiftUI.(unknown context at $1248d26b0).FontBox<SwiftUI.Font.(unknown context at $12492b8dc).PlatformFontProvider>)
    NSKern = 0.0
    NSParagraphStyle = Alignment Natural, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode WordWrapping, Tabs (
), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (
), Lists (
), BaseWritingDirection LeftToRight, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0 LineBreakStrategy 0 PresentationIntents (
) ListIntentOrdinal 0 CodeBlockIntentLanguageHint ''
}
    ▿ _guts : <Guts: 0x600002446e80>
```

Want to check if `remark: AttributedString?` is empty or not?

Comment: Did you try to check `characters`?
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributedstring/3765837-characters

Comment: Yes this will not work, because it return space `character `

Comment: So you could filter out whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

You can check the number of characters in the `AttributedString`. So in your case, to check if the `remark` is not empty, do this:

```swift
if !remark.characters.isEmpty {
  // show your view
}
```

Comment: ```(lldb) po remark?.characters.count
▿ Optional<Int>
  - some : 3 ```

Comment: it will always return false because remark have 3 spaces

Comment: That does not make sense. Why does it have 3 spaces? This works fine:

```swift
var string = AttributedString("hello")
print(string.characters.count) // returns 5

string = AttributedString("")
print(string.characters.count) // returns 0
```

If you know that it has 3 spaces, just check whether all characters are 3 spaces and take a decision based on that